# How to go back to the Windows Phone app page after hiding the windows phone browser user control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I have developed a windows phone user control which has only Browser control in it's grid.
I am navigating to this Browser control from my main page of app upon clicking a button. This browser control load Facebook authentication page.After posting the message to facebook , I want to go back to my main app .

For this I tried to hide the Browser control and i have set visibility to collapsed,and it shows a blank screen.

Any help on how can I go back  to the main app which has called this browser control and maintain the same state as before  ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works...

```
 (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).GoBack()
```